# How to publish a specific Folder in Jenkins Git Publisher

Tags: git, bash, jenkins, bitbucket

I have a short question: How can I publish Files from a specific Folder to Git using Git Publisher in Jenkins?

**Example:**

I clone my Sourcecode from a Git-Repo in the Subfolder `/git`. Next, I build the Application and copy the compiled Files in the Subfolder `/compiled`. Finally, I only want to publish the Content of the Subfolder `/compiled` to my second Git-Repo.